# Building JAR file with IntelliJ, OpenJFX and Gradle

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea, openjfx

What is in 2021 the best way to create an executable jar file with Gradle in IntelliJ using OpenJFX? Every solution I found is very complex and uses workarounds. This is my current build.gradle file

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'application'
    id 'org.openjfx.javafxplugin' version '0.0.9'
}

tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    options.encoding = "UTF-8"
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

javafx {
    version = "15.0.1"
    modules = [ 'javafx.controls', 'javafx.fxml' ]
}

mainClassName = 'com.company.crawl.main.Main'

group 'com.company'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
    compile group: 'com.google.code.gson', name: 'gson', version: '2.8.6'
    compile group: 'com.microsoft.sqlserver', name: 'mssql-jdbc', version: '9.2.0.jre15'
    compile group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-lang3', version: '3.11'
    compile group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-csv', version: '1.8'
}

jar {
    from configurations.compile.collect {zipTree it}
    manifest.attributes "Main-Class": "com.company.crawl.main.Main"
}
```

If I run gradle :jar, the jar file includes the dependencies but not the openjfx sdk. What do I have to do to run the jar using the openjfx sdk?

**UPDATE 1**

changed the jar path to this:

```
jar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'com.company.crawl.main.Main'
    }
    from {
        configurations.runtimeClasspath.collect {it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it)}
    }
}
```

after rebuilding the jar, I get the error: "JavaFX runtime components are missing". I don't know why because in the jar file the javafx folders are included. After that I added the VM options:

```
--module-path /path/to/javafx-sdk/lib --add-modules=javafx.controls,javafx.fxml
```

and the jar file runs. So what am I doing wrong?